# Unexpected implicit casting in Solidity's exponential operator

Tags: bug, solc

While investigating an incorrect token award bug in an ERC20, it's come to light that there is an apparent inconsistency in casting with regard to the exponential operator `a**b`. In particular, the output casts to type `b` rather than type `a`.

So when calculating a decimal place exponent `10**exp` where `exp` is defined `uint8 exp = 3` the output is truncated to 8 bit giving the answer of `232` rather than `1000`.

If the base is definded as `uint8` and exponent of longer type, e.g.`uint`, the compiler will throw an implicit conversion error which indicates the output should be of type base and not exponent.

This doesn't seem to be affected by non-compound parameters which are all cast to 32bit slots anyway.

```
contract PowerOfTest {
    // Returns 232
    uint8 public placesA = 3;
    uint public EXP_A = 10**placesA;

    // Returns 1000
    uint public placesB = 3;
    uint public EXP_B = 10**placesB;

    // Returns 1000
    uint8 public placesC = 3;
    uint public EXP_C = 10**uint(placesC);

    // Type uint256 is not implicity convertable to expected type uint 8
    // uint public EXP_D = 3;
    // uint8 public placesD = 10**EXP_D;

    // Returns 1000 for `pow(10, 3)`
    function pow(uint base, uint8 exponent) returns(uint)
    {
        return base**exponent;
    }

    // Returns 232 for `pow(10, 3)`
    function pow2() returns(uint)
    {
        uint8 EXP_D = 3;
        return 10**EXP_D;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @chriseth responding to the GH issue raised...

> The result type of any binary operator in Solidity (also admitting that ** as a non-commutative operator should be treated differently) is a type that can fit both argument types. The result of the expression a**b is always the "larger" type of a and b. Note that the type of the variable the result of the expression is assigned to does not influence the type of the expression itself.
>
> As a solution, I would suggest to use uint(10)**placesA and the compiler should add a warning whenever the base of a ** operator is a constant.
>
> ... constants assume the smallest type they fit into as soon as they hit a non-constant.

Further reading on the maths and type casting of [literals](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals).