# How do I ensure that `1 << n` is executed as a 256-bit operation?

Tags: solidity, overflow

In other words, how do I ensure that `1 << n` does not overflow for `n < 256`?

At present, I am using `uint256(1) << n`.

Is there a better way, or is it guaranteed that the expression `uint256(1)` is replaced with a constant value during compilation (and not computed during runtime)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Solidity documentation, in the case of `1<<n`, `1` will remain arbitrarily precise until converted to non-literal types, so you should be ok.

> Number literal expressions retain arbitrary precision until they are converted to a non-literal type (i.e. by using them together with a non-literal expression). This means that computations do not overflow and divisions do not truncate in number literal expressions.

[1] http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

Comment: Well that's funny, I have observed that a simple `1 << n` is consistently truncated long before `n` reaches 256 (didn't quite check when, but I have presumed that it overflows at `n == 8`, due to the fact that `1` fits in a `uint8`).

Comment: In fact, here's a warning from Remix, when trying to return `1 << n` from a function which returns `uint256`: "Warning: Result of shift has type uint8 and thus might overflow. Silence this warning by converting the literal to the expected type.".

Answer (score 1):

Constants in the source code can be cast with types offering the least precision that will support the value. That can lead to trouble. [Unexpected implicit casting in Solidity's exponential operator](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12723/unexpected-implicit-casting-in-soliditys-exponential-operator)

You can avoid that kind of trouble by explicitly casting them with high precision.

Consider.

```
if(uint(1) < n) {}
```

Hope it helps.