# Integer type in solidity

Tags: solidity

I have come across statements like uint256(0) and address(0). What is the meaning of that?

For example this statement in solidity docs
`uint256(0) - uint256(1) == 2**256 - 1`

Answer (score 2):

It's just casting a value explicity into a specific type. There are a few everyday uses for it.

As a guard:

`require(msg.sender != address(0), "You forgot to populate the address field.");`

It's also useful for constants in a contract because, by default, they will cast to the smallest possible precision.

This example is a little contrived because Solidity has improved since this: [Unexpected implicit casting in Solidity's exponential operator](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12723/unexpected-implicit-casting-in-soliditys-exponential-operator).

```
pragma solidity 0.5.8;

contract Cast {

    function weirdResult() public pure returns(uint) {
        uint8 y = 3;
        uint8 x = 10;
        return x**y;
    }
}
```

***10 to the power of 3 is 232?*** Yikes!

You will see constants wrapped in a type to avoid all doubt about how they should be cast. It's a good safety habit.

`return uint(10)**uint(3); // less possibility of misinterpretation`

instead of

`return 10**3;`

As a general style thing, I like to avoid using any hard-coded values deep in the contracts and declare them up front, instead.

```
address constant NULL_ADDRESS = address(0);
bytes32 constant NULL_KEY = bytes32(0);
```

You could even

```
uint constant NO_MONEY = uint(0);

...

require(msg.value != NO_MONEY, "You have to send some ether.");
```

Hope it helps.