# Use uint[] to map uint(address) to uint

Tags: solidity, gas, dapps, evm

Is there any reason not to use

```
uint[2**160-1] addressIndex;
```

instead of

```
mapping(address => uint) addressIndex;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The answer below refers to the difference between:

- a `mapping(address => uint)`
- an array of `struct {address key; uint value;}` elements

Which is not what's being asked here.

I'm leaving it here because I feel that it still contributes something in the context of this question...

---

I hope that this table answers your question:

```
|----------------|---------|-------|
|                | Mapping | Array |
|----------------|---------|-------|
| Add an item    | O(1)    | O(1)  |
|----------------|---------|-------|
| Remove an item | O(1)    | O(n)  |
|----------------|---------|-------|
| Find an item   | O(1)    | O(n)  |
|----------------|---------|-------|
```

You should choose an array over a mapping only if any of the following restrictions is given:

1. The order of the items is important
2. The keys of the mapping are not provided by the user

Comment: I think the table confusing. What does it mean "find an item" for a mapping? Maybe it is accessing an item with its key? What does it mean for an array? Maybe it is searching a value?

Comment: @Ismael: Yeah, I'm just now realizing that what this dude has posted is an array which serves as a lookup table, which is not feasible for this range in "traditional" systems (where this range implies a huge memory consumption), but is possibly feasible on the blockchain (I guess the question is whether or not this is feasible). I was answering a different question, as I now understand, namely, why not use an array over a mapping (in which case, the array would be storing tuples of "key,value", and the complexity would be as described in my answer). This is obviously a different question.

Comment: @Ismael: So will probably delete this answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

They are approximately the same.

Your fixed-size array lays out a very large address space where every possible address equivalent has a slot. That's logically equivalent to what `mapping` does, although laid out differently (See Ismael's comment below) and slight different in gas cost as a result.

I would incline to the mapping for readability. Solidity calls for strong preference for idiomatic, readable code so there is an argument against verbosity.

There is a slight, almost insignificant gas efficiency advantage to the array with this little example (view is intentionally removed to get some gas accounting from Remix).

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

contract ArrayMapping {

    uint[2**160-1] addressIndex;
    mapping(address => uint) mapped;

    function getArray(uint row) public returns (uint) { // <== 1128 gas
        return addressIndex[row];
    }

    function getMap(address a) public returns (uint) { // <== 1174 gas
        return mapped[a];
    }
}
```

In case it is helpful, this tutorial lays out some ways to use arrays and mappings together. https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Or, you might be interested in: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Also, your intent is clear, but it might be a good idea to be explicit about typecasting to be certain that your expression does what you think it does. IIRC there have been changes to the *implicit* casting, but why not be explicit?

```
uint(uint(2)**uint(160)-uint(1)) addressIndex;
```

This is to be sure you don't fall into a trap along these lines: [Unexpected implicit casting in Solidity's exponential operator](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12723/unexpected-implicit-casting-in-soliditys-exponential-operator)

Hope it helps.

Comment: The difference is that mapping require a keccak256(slot + key) to calculate where to read from and for an array it can be precalculated keccak256(slot) + index.

Comment: Good point. I edited a little to capture this. Thanks.